# Powershell: How to throw an error if a CSV entry is blank

Tags: csv, powershell, if-statement, try-catch, custom-error-handling

I've written an extensive script that runs through an AD termination process, and the script can obtain the necessary information from a CSV. How do I make it so that it errors out if the entry is blank in the CSV? I've tried putting in Try-Catch, If-Else, everything that I know how to do. I've tried changing the error action, and I can get it to throw system generated errors (ex. "Cannot bind parameter "Identity" to the target..."), but I cannot get it to do what I want. Please see the code example below:

(Yes, I know that I'm duplicating values. This of importance later on in the script, and not the part I'm having issues with)

```
    $owner = $user.'Network User ID'}
    $loginID = $user.'Network User ID'
    $Identity = Get-ADUser -Identity $owner -Properties Displayname |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Displayname 
    $manager = $user.'Provide Inbox Access To'
    $NewOwner = $user.'Provide users email group ownership to'
    $NewOwnerID = $User.'Provide users email group ownership To'
```

What I need it to do is throw an error if ANY entry in the CSV is blank, and terminate. The most promising idea that I tried was:

```
    If ($Owner -eq $Null)
    {
    Write-Host "Invalid entry, the Network User ID field cannot be blank"
    Write-Host "Press Enter to Exit..."
    Exit
    }
    Else
    {
    #Do everything else
    }
```

But even that still fails.

In summary, what I need to do is throw a custom terminating error if an entry in the CSV is blank.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT

If this helps, here is more of the real code...

```
$Confirmation = Read-Host "Please double check the information in the file. Are you sure you want to continue? (Y/N)"

If($Confirmation -eq "Y")
{
Write-Host "You have chosen to proceed. Processing Termination" -BackgroundColor DarkCyan
#Import file
$file = "C:\TerminateUsers.csv"
$data = Import-Csv $file
#Set disabled OU
$disabledOU = "OU=Users,OU=Disabled Accounts, OU=Corporate"

$colOutput = @()
foreach ($user in $data)
{
    #Grab variables from CSV
    $owner = $user.'Terminated Network User ID'}
    $loginID = $user.'Terminated Network User ID'

    #Displayname required for Outlook functions
    $Identity = Get-ADUser -Identity $owner -Properties Displayname |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Displayname 
    $manager = $user.'Provide Inbox Access To'
    $NewOwner = $user.'Provide users email group ownership to'
    $NewOwnerID = $User.'Provide users email group ownership To'
    If (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$loginID)")
        {
        $date = Get-Date -Format d
        #Disable account, change description, disable dialin, remove group memberships
        Set-ADUser -Identity $loginID -Enabled $false
        Set-ADUser -Identity $loginID -Replace @{Description = "Terminated $date"}
        Set-ADUser -Identity $loginID -Replace @{msNPAllowDialin = $False}
        RemoveMemberships $loginID
```

This isn't all of it, but this is the part we're working with...

Comment: I'd also like to note that I've tried just running the if-else and try-catch statements without the rest of the script by just running that block in a separate tab. This still doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of issues you're going to run into here.

First, `$Owner -eq $Null` isn't going to do what you likely want to do.  Mainly, the issue is that an empty string is not a null value.  They're different.  Instead, your test should be:

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($owner)) { ... }
```

Or:

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($owner)) { ... }
```

This second one returns true if the string includes only tabs, spaces, or other whitespace characters, or is an empty string, or is null.

Second, to throw an exception, you need to use the `throw` keyword.  See `Get-Help about_Throw`.  For example:

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($owner)) {
    throw "Owner is null or empty.";
}
```

If you have this embedded in a `try` block, you can catch the exception with the associated `catch` blocks.  See `Get-Help about_Try_Catch_Finally`.  You can also use `Trap`, I believe  (See `Get-Help about_Trap`).

Finally, the default action when an error is encountered is controlled by the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable.  That variable's default value is `Continue`, so error messages will be displayed but the script will continue executing as though no error happened at all.  I'm not entirely sure how this works with manually thrown exceptions and try/catch blocks, but unless I *know* that I want my script to ignore errors, I start just about every script with:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = Stop;
```

See `Get-Help about_Preference_Variables` and `Get-Help about_CommonParameters` for more about this one.

Comment: I might have understood the question wrong but he asked: _What I need it to do is throw an error if ANY entry in the CSV is blank, and terminate_. This would work only if you check every column individually would it not?

Comment: @Matt Hm, I agree, but I guess I interpreted the script differently.  I assumed there was a `foreach ($user in $myCsvFile) { ...` before the snippet.

Comment: I've added more of the block of code that I'm working with, hoping it will help you better understand what I'm doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following dataset. Note the null for Last_Name for one of the columns.

```
user_name  first_name last_name
---------  ---------- ---------
lrivera0   Lawrence   Rivera   
tlawrence1 Theresa    Lawrence 
rboyd2     Roy                 
cperry3    Christine  Perry    
jmartin4   Jessica    Martin
```

So if we want to be sure to only process full rows then a simple `If` would cover that.

```
Import-Csv .\text.csv | ForEach-Object{
  If($_.Psobject.Properties.Value -contains ""){
     # There is a null here somewhere
     Throw "Null encountered. Stopping"
  } else {
    # process as normal
  }
}
```

Problem is that `Import-CSV` treats nulls as zero length strings. I tried using `-contains` on just `$_` but it did not work as `$_` is not an array but an object with properties. So I used the object properties `value` to perform the comparison against.

Bacon brought up an interesting point in that this code would not account for whitespace only empty values.

We use `throw` so processing stops if a null is encountered. Using that if block you can do whatever action you want.

Comment: `Import-CSV .\text.csv | %{$_.psobject.Properties|?{$_.Name -eq 'values'}|Select -expand value|?{$_ -match "^\s*$"}|%{Throw "Null encountered. Stopping";Exit}}` - Checks each value of each property of each record for null or whitespace, and if any are found throws your error and exits.